# page A post values to page B that makes another post to page C using cURL and return response back to page A

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, curl

I`m facing a situation that's really new to me. I'll try to make things simple explaining it 
step by step.

1)In page A (User's form), I'm getting some values from the fields and sending it as jQuery AJAX POST to page B. This is the main piece of code and it's working fine:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

var options = { 
    target:        '#my-container',
    dataType:      'html',   
    beforeSubmit:  showRequest,  // pre-submit callback 
    success:       processOK,  // post-submit callback 
    error:         processError,
    clearForm:     false
}; 

// bind form using 'ajaxForm' 
$('#myForm').ajaxForm(options); 
});
```

I'm defining "url action" and "method as POST" directly in the form definition.

2) Page B is receiving the POST values from page A correctly and using it to make another POST to page C, but this time using cURL. At this time, everything still working as desired. I can read the response in page B, and it's fine. Here is the code:

PAGE B CODE:

```
<?php
$cURL = curl_init('http://200.201.194.133/exampleurl/MakeCall.php');
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

 $dados = array(
    'type' => '0',
            'dest' => $_POST["dest"],
            'content' => $_POST["content"],
            'priority' => '-1',
    'return' => '1',
    'answer' => '40',
    'ringtime' => '26',
    'psid' => 'ct1253117',
    'ctid' => '9'
);

curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dados);

$result = curl_exec($cURL);
curl_close($cURL);
echo "<span class='response'>OK</span>"; 
?>
```

3) Here comes the problem, When page B receives de response from page C, it displays the response in the browser, and I need this response to be sent do page A where a can capture it in de jQuery AJAX callback functions. Page A (User's form) needs to be visible all time.

I've spent all my day trying to solve this problem before ask for help. So, I'll be very glad if anyone can help me with this situation. Alternative solution is welcome too.

EDITED:(Original function - this way it don't work, I don't know why, even adding the line "return false").

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

var options = { 
    target:        '#my-container',
    dataType:      'html',   
    beforeSubmit:  showRequest,  // pre-submit callback 
    success:       processOK,  // post-submit callback 
    error:         processError,
    clearForm:     false
}; 

// bind form using 'ajaxForm' 
$('#myForm').ajaxForm(options); 
});
```

CHANGED TO: (now it works - attention to the line "return false;", it's important)

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(e)
{
var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
$.ajax(
{
    url : formURL,
    type: "POST",
    success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
    {
        alert("success");
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
    {
        alert("fail");    
    }
});
//STOP default action
return false;
});

$("#myForm").submit();
```

Comment: This means your form submit handler isn't preventing the default submit action, therefore the page does a full postback to page b, then page b gets and returns the content of page c. ajax isn't being used at all.

Comment: If the response is displayed in the browser, I think the problem exists with you javascript from PageA.  It looks like you are using the jQuery Form Plugin; I have had problems configuring this plugin before.  Do you still have the same problem is you ommit the Form Plugin [ http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ ] ?

Comment: Before submitting your form, press Ctrl+shift+j to open your console(F12 in IE) and reload the page. Do you see any errors in the error console?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. As soon as I can test this answers I'll give a feedback.

Comment: Thanks everybody, all of you helped me with part of the answer. I just updated my post with the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the jQuery AJAX Plugin, I changed the way AJAX function is being declared and now it's working as desired. See the EDIT and CHANGED sections in the code of this post to get the right code.

Thanks for the comments, helped a lot!